# Value and Reference types confusion

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

I was on every website about this topic and was reading the past few days through Jon Skeets´s article about [References and Values](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html) and [Parameter passing](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html). I understood the concept of those two types, what they stand for and the difference to Value and Reference parameters what is another specification.

I understand how this works and how you can use it, but i dont understand something everbody says about this topic. You all out there say that for example `int` is a value type and `string` is a reference type. But according to my understanding the type basically just depends on the kind of class in which they got declared.

Have a look at this code snippet to understand what i mean:

```
public struct IntHolder
{
   public int number;
}

IntHolder first = new IntHolder();
first.number = 5;
IntHolder second = first;
first.number = 6;
```

Now `second.number` has the value 5. If you change `struct` to `class`, `number` will act like a reference type, so it doesnt matter at all that `int` is in generell a value type, its just about the type of the class. Same example goes for `string`, etc... .

So apparently the type of the class where the object gets declared sets the type of its objects or i missunderstand a core concept. Please either correct me and help me to understand it correct or tell what is the sense behind saying  that `int` `string`, etc...has a special type even though it does not matter when they get initialised, so basically always.

Comment: IntHolder second = first; created a new struct and not a reference to the first one. Also passing an argument to a method by reference does not have anything to do with the reference/value types distinction

Comment: "Now second.number has the value 5. If you change struct to class, number will act like a reference type" - no, that's not true at all. If you change struct to class `IntHolder` will be a reference type, but `int` will still be a value type.

Comment: Ok now i know at least one if my wrong conclusion. So when i assign `IntHolder` as a reference type and later on do this `IntHolder second = first;` second will be a reference to first what is a reference to the created IntHolder object. So when i change the value of the object with the reference first, it is automatically the same value for the object second is pointing to, because its the same. Right? But then how does the type of for example `int` matter at all?

Comment: Doing `second = first` with reference types *copies the reference*. `second` will have nothing to do with `first` except that it’s an exact copy of the variable, being a reference pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the type of the field you are changing. What is relevant here is indeed just the kind of the parent type:

```
IntHolder first = new IntHolder();
IntHolder second = first;
```

Depending on the kind of `IntHolder` this has two different effects:

For value types (`struct`), this creates a *copy*. The data of the value type object lives *with* the object, so all of it is copied. It’s kind of equivalent to this:

```
IntHolder second = new IntHolder();
second.number = first.number;
// and all other fields (visible or not) are copied too
```

This means that an assignment to a field of the *copied* value type will overwrite that value without affecting the original object. It’s like how a local variable behaves:

```
var x = 5;
var y = 2;
y = 3; // this does not change x
```

However, when the type is a reference type, the assignment `second = first` just copies *the reference*. The underlying object where the values are kept are the same for both. So changes to either object affect the other—because there is no *“other”*: it’s the same object that’s just being referenced by two separate variables.

---

To answer the follow-up questions from the comment:

> How do I need to imagine it that an `int` variable is a value type and `string` is a reference type? I mean, so the `int` variable directly contains the number and the `string` variable is just like a pointer to a storage location of the string object?

Yes, that’s exactly it. The value of a reference is basically just a pointer to the memory where the object actually is, while the value of a value type is the whole object itself.

That’s why e.g. having a value type as the parameter to a method means that when the method is called, the whole value type object is copied into the stack for the execution of the method.

A type being a value type does not mean that its members will all be value types too though. For example, the actually stored value of a string member inside a value type is still a reference to the string object. Similarly, the actual memory for a reference type will contain the actual value for value types, and references to *other* memory locations for reference types.

> If the parent type always matter more than the objects types, what can I use the type of int and string for?

There is nothing that matters more than another. An object being a value or a reference type has only implications on how that object is stored. For members of the object, this is evaluated completely separately.

> Is it possible if you just have one class and a bunch of variables to set some of them just as a reference to another variable, for example `int` variables.

You cannot have a reference pointer for a value type, like you could have in C, no. But you can have references to fields which allow you to mutate the value of fields that are of a value type. For example:

```
class Test
{
    private int field;

    public void ShowExample()
    {
        // set the value
        field = 12;

        // call the method and pass *a reference* to the field
        // note the special syntax
        MutateField(ref field);

        // the field, which is a value type, was mutated because it was passed as a reference
        Console.WriteLine(field == 4);
    }

    private static void MutateField(ref int value)
    {
        value = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but i have a few questions left. First: Is it possible if you just have one class and a bunch of variables to set some of them just as a reference to another variable, for example `int` variables. Next, if the parent type always matter more than the objects types, what can i use the type of `int` and `string` for? And the last thing is how do i need to imagine it that a `int` variable is a value type and `string` is a reference type. I mean so the int variable directly contains the number and the string variable is just like a pointer to a storage location of the string object?

Comment: @L.Guthardt Expanded my answer for those follow-up questions.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this detailed answer. Unfortenately i cant give you more reputation. I have only just one more question left, then i leave you alone. :) When i execute a method and the method gets a parameter at the beginning, no matter if this is a value or reference type variable (so like `int` or `string`) the given parameter for the method is just a copy right? Thats why i cant change in this method the object itself, even though the variable was of reference type. because the parameter is just a copy of this object, if i dont mark it with `ref`.

Comment: So when i execute a method with a parameter does it only matter if i mark it with `ref` that it either gets copied on the stack or not, referring to that it is a whole object or just a reference then? So does the parameter type matter or the reference and value type of the object as well?

Comment: No, when you pass an object to a method, you basically have the same effect as when you do `var parameterValue = value`. So for value types, the method receives an independent copy, and for reference types, the method receives a copy of the reference, so *mutating* the object will mutate the original object as well. That’s why I can pass e.g. a list to a method and have that method fill the list for me. When passing `ref`, you essentially pass a reference to the variable/field and are able to change *that* (instead of just the value).

Comment: Ok thank you. But i mean as well if i have `string random = "Hello"`, this `string` is as well the parameter for a method. So when i pass it without `ref` and to the method and change its value in the method `inputParameter = "modified text"` and i acess the value of the `string` outside the method it is still "Hello" right? Because i just changed the value of the copy of the reference. But if i pass e.g. an empty list still without `ref` and add something to it `randomList.Add()` and acess the list outside of the method the list will be filled right?

Comment: When you do `inputParameter = "modified text"` you are not *changing* the value of the passed string object. You are replacing the reference to the passed string object with a reference to that new string object. So you are losing access to the string object that was originally passed to the method. Strings are also generally immutable, so you cannot change a string once it has been created. If there was a `String.AppendCharacter` or something, then you would see the same as you do when you mutate the list.

Comment: Ok i got that now. Thank you very much. But what do you mean by "Strings are also generally immutable, so you cannot change a string once it has been created." I mean i can change its value, thats for sure not what you mean. I guess you mean when i have a reference e.g. called "randomString" to a `string` object, i cant assign "randomString" as a new reference to a another `string` object?

Comment: No, you cannot change the value of a string object. By doing `foo = "bar"` you create *a new string* and assign that (its reference) to `foo`. By calling `foo.ToUpperCase()`, you are creating *a new string* again. String objects cannot change, they are immutable. – You are mixing up variables with references. The value of a string variable is the reference to the string object. By assigning a string to that variable, you are assigning (=replacing) a copy of the reference to the new string object to the variable.

Comment: "The value of a string variable is the reference to the string object." yes i got that, but then i am curious how i have to imagine this: I mean if i have `string foo= "text"` so i create a new object of the type `string` and assign foo as its reference and the string object contains the value "text". So if i do this: `foo = "modified"` i guess i dont change foo it self, because it is only the reference to the string object and if i would change the reference i would loose access to my string object and as i am not creating a new string object i dont change the reference.

Comment: So the code is smart enough that even though i say i want to change the value of foo by `=` it changes the value of the string object? Or what exactly does happen there? Because i think here is the point that i dont understand, because you say a string object is immutable and i cant imagine what that means. I mean i can change the objects´s value, but what do you mean by saying that i cant change the object itself. What would be changing a complete object, e.g. what would that mean about an `int` object or is this a whole new aspect as its a value type?

Comment: If you do `foo = "modified"` you are modifying `foo` the variable name, but not `foo` the object `foo` previously referenced. So yes, the old object becomes detached from `foo` and if you do not have another reference to the object, it gets “lost” (and eventually garbage collected). – When you assign something, you are not changing some value, you are merely changing what the variable references. The previous value will not be affected by this. You are not changing objects, you are simply labeling new things (those being values for value types, or references to objects for reference types).

Comment: Ok so i think i understand my mistake. I thought that i can only create a new object if i place there any keyword. Take this example, i have this: `string foo = "whatever"` and then i assign `foo = "modified"`. So i assume according to you that i created with that `foo = "modified"` a complete new string object even though i didnt place any keyword? At the same time i lost any access to the string object that contained the value "whatever", right?