# How to properly return a list item for editing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns, builder

I created a class for convenient creation of a list that consists of different types of objects with a single interface.

A list item is created by calling a class method, the result of the method is a newly created object in the list for EDIT.

While this code works, I'm not sure if it's safe to return a list item to edit properties?

If not, how can you safely return an element from the list so that you can edit it.

```cs
var builder = new ElementBuilder();
var item = builder.AddText("abc");

// Edit new reference element property, should be stored in "builder" variable
item.Bold = true;

.....

// Pass builder instance with added items to other place

// If we do something like this with added values on above
var x = builder.First() as TextElement; 
Console.WriteLine(x.Text);
Console.WriteLine(x.Bold);

// Should output:
abc
true
```

```cs
public class ElementBuilder
{

    private List<IElement> elements =  new List<IElement>();;

    public TextElement AddText (string text)
    {
        var item = new TextElement (text);
        elements.Add(item);
// RETURNING to edit properties, updates of returning should affect to list item
        return _elements.First(x => x == item);
    }

    public ImageElement AddImage (string imageUrl)
    {
        var item = new ImageElement (imageUrl);
        elements.Add(item);

// RETURNING to edit properties, updates of returning should affect to list item
        return _elements.First(x => x == item);
    }

    public IElement First() 
    {
        return elements.First();
    }

    .....
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? Also, `.First(x => x == item)` is redundant. You can just `return item;`. Are you trying to allow the caller to not only modify the returned element, but also _replace_ it in the list? Because yes, that wouldn't work with the code above.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine What I mean is that the newly created element in the list is returned from the method as a "reference" (I assume).

Is it possible to guarantee that when updating the "reference" properties, the property of the same element in the list will be updated?

Comment: Of course it is. Consider this example. Let's assume that you have a list of people's names and all those people are wearing red shirts. You call a name from that list and tell the person to go and see me. I give the person a blue shirt, which they put on in place of their red shirt. If you call that person's name again later, is it safe to assume that they will be wearing a blue shirt when the present to you? Of course it is. Anything else would be magic. Programming is not magic.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your answer, however I would be glad to hear the answer like "I used this design" or "there is such a project that used this design".

Comment: @jmcilhinney It works and it seems to me that it works like magic, because I could not find a similar class design.

Comment: Every project works the same way. That's how reference types work... everywhere, every time. Each list item is basically a variable. Just like a variable, if it refers to an object then it will continue to refer to that same object unless you assign a different object to it. If you don't change the list, the list won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it's safe to return a list item to edit properties?

yeah, it is safe because what code is doing is it returns the reference to newly created item:

```
var item = new TextElement (text);
```

There are really nice posts how reference types work:

- [Value and Reference types confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45589951)
- [Reference type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18229505)

In addition, it is possible to avoid iteration of the whole collection by returning `item`, not using `First()` method:

```
public IElement AddText (string text)
{
    var item = new TextElement (text);
    elements.Add(item);
    
    return item;
}
```

Because when you `Add` item into collection, then newly created item will be added at the end of list. So, `First()` method will iterate the whole `List<T>` to find your item. [It can be seen in source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs) of `First()` method.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer, that's what I wanted to know. Thanks!